# All files in a directory will have 770 and git:www-data (Linux)

Tags: linux, permissions, git

Can I somehow specify that:

- in a **directory** repository.git
- **all** files will **ALWAYS** have
- mode **770** and
- **git:www-dat** a ownwership:groupship?

Answer (score 1):

permissions - mount with ACL options
ownership - Your looking at setuid and setgid bits... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

an example of what it looks like you are trying to do is here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/applying-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-within-a-specific-folder-605129/

Answer (score 1):

If you can enforce that applications that create files in this directory run with umask 007, and create files with no restriction on permissions, and run with group `www-data` as their effective or supplementary group, then all you need to do is `chmod g+s repository.git`. Otherwise, you can't do *exactly* what you request.

However, if you make the directory itself owned by `git:www-data` and mode 770, only the `git` user and the `www-data` group will be able to access files in the directory. Even if the files in the directory are world-readable, other users won't be able to access them unless they're hard linked elsewhere or you hand them a descriptor to the directory (which you'd pretty much have to do deliberately).

Next is the problem of making the files group-writable. You can do that if the filesystem has [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List) enabled. For ext2/ext3/ext4/reiserfs, make sure it's mounted with the `acl` options. Install the ACL command line tools (e.g. you need the `acl` package on Debian or Ubuntu).

```
chmod 770 repository.git
chown git:www-data repository.git
setfacl -m user:git:rwx -m group:www-data:rwx repository.git
setfacl -d -m user:git:rwx -m group:www-data:rwx repository.git
```

I don't think the files will end up executable unless the applications create them to be executable. I don't know how to remedy this.